# parse xml data which have special characters and other symbols like in spanish and dutch language

Tags: iphone

I'm having problems with NSXMLParser while parsing XML File which contain
some special characters or Non-UTF Characters,

My application will get the XML Document data from my server.  I'm creating
the NSXMLParser with NSData received from Server. Some times it could be
possible that received NSData may contain special characters such as "Ä?" ,
then parser stops itself and returns an error saying Invalid Character
Found. Here is the Exact Error am receiving ---

*NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 9*

Please provide your valuable suggestions to solve the problem.

Comment: Which parser delegate methods are you using? `– parser:foundCharacters:` or `– parser:foundCDATA:`. (I assume `– parser:foundCDATA:`.) Could you also add a sample of the XML that is causing the error (the problem may be poorly formed XML).

Comment: '-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string'